# IN/OUT access to addresses above 2^16?

Tags: assembly, io, x86, x86-16

How can I load/store data to the periphery which address is bigger than 2<sup>16</sup> with IN/OUT instructions.

When I use IN/OUT instruction, lets say `OUT DX, AL`, I know that the segment register of DX is not used so I can access only the first 2<sup>16</sup> addresses (because DX is 16 bits wide).

One of my devices is on the address `18000h`. How can I reach it? The memory/IO space overlaps (the M/IO pin is not used), so is it ok to say something like

```
MOV BX, 18000h
MOV [BX], AL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't with `IN or OUT` instruction!

The x86 processor supports an I/O address space that contains up to 65,536 8-bit I/O
ports.

From Intel datasheet:

> > The processor permits applications to
> >     access I/O ports in either of two
> >     ways:
> >
> > - Through a separate I/O address space
> > - Through memory-mapped I/O
>
> Accessing I/O ports through the I/O
>   address space is handled through a set
>   of I/O instructions and a special I/O
>   protection mechanism. Accessing I/O
>   ports through memory-mapped I/O is
>   handled with the processors
>   general-purpose move and string
>   instructions, with protection provided
>   through segmentation or paging. I/O
>   ports can be mapped so that they
>   appear in the I/O address space or the
>   physicalmemory address space (memory
>   mapped I/O) or both.

Comment: Ok, I know that already. I changed the schema. That organization was needlessly complicate. Now all peripheries are below 65536, so it should work fine (at least on the paper:)). Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Technically, you can access "port number 0xFFFF" as a 16-bit or 32-bit IO port. Intel warns about this in their documentation for the IO Permission Bitmap (in a Task State Segment)